# Replace node names in a graph

Tags: r, graph, replace, nodes, igraph

I have made a graph using igraph package. Node names are probe_IDs and I want to replace them with geneSYMOLs.

```
> summary(graph)
IGRAPH UNW- 10092 23453 -- 
attr: name (v/c), weight (e/n)
```

and I have Unige Ids as below:

```
"1552263_at"   "225469_at"    "204531_s_at"  "238149_at"    "229285_at"   
"226075_at"    "237016_at"    "1552632_a_at"
```

Can anyone help me? I have also a matrix that has each probeID with its related symbol.
Thanks

Comment: Please post a small example for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Try `V(graph)$name <- my_matrix[V(graph)$name]`

Comment: "Reproducible" would have involved posting output from `dput(graph)` and `dput(ids)`.

Comment: You need a mapping from your probe ids to gene symbols. Do you have that? In what form? If you don't have it, find the appropriate BioConductor package that has it.

Comment: I'm using annotation package and have prepared the mapping file using: SYMBOLS<-(getSYMBOL(names, "hgu133plus2.db")) command